# store a Certificate in a TPM?

Tags: certificates

Is there any point to store a Certificate in a TPM?

From what I understand a certificate is public knowledge.  The only concern about certificates is accepting a rogue certificate.

Comment: private or public certificate?

Comment: Ok, good point.  But if private certificates are to be controlled, only distributed within a company (for example), it seems pretty easy for one to leak during distribution from human factor alone.  After that, with authorization a private Certificate is released from the TPM (for TLS), and again potential to be leaked.

Comment: The difference between a cert issued by a public authority and a private party is not so much that of confidential data and privacy, but of the ability to establish trust. If I can authenticate a cert chain that is anchored to a globally trusted root, then it is something that can be shared with anyone and still have a common level of trust. On the other hand, a cert issued by a private party can really only be shared in a small group. If it gets out, it just isn't trusted by others--it's not a "leak" of private data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few certificates that make sense to store in a TPM, and each of them is a certificate for, or relating to the TPM. The endorsement key (EK) certificate, often issued by the TPM manufacturer can be stored on the TPM. Platform certificates, conformance certificates, and platform conformance certificates can also be stored on the TPM. Each of those certs I listed have a designated index to store in TPM NV storage, however, any blob of data--certificate or otherwise--can be stored on the TPM, as long as there is available space.

The reason to store anything in the TPM is that the storage can be persistent on the computer. It's not on the hard drive, and not managed by an operating system. The TPM and platform manufacturers put TPM certificates on the TPM so that they are available when the end user partitions the drives and loads an operating system. Depending on the situation, an end user might want to store other data there for the same reasons. For example, dual booting to encrypted volumes, or swapping drives between OSes, if you want to store some bit of data. That data might even be an encrypted identity key blob.

The TPM's NV storage is limited, somewhat slow, and difficult to manage. It should not be used except for situations where the advantages outweigh the drawbacks. That is very few situations.

TPM certs are, for the most part, just like any other certificate. The EK certificate is a public key certificate, holding the public portion of the TPM's life-long identity/storage key. It is generally signed by the TPM manufacturer. You must still validate it using a cert chain which can be obtained from the manufacturer's web site. To know that the TPM holds the private portion of that key, you will need to perform one of the few actions that force the TPM to decrypt something that you encrypted with the public key found in the certificate. After you have done these tasks, you should have a high assurance that the certificate is valid. The platform certificate is an attribute certificate, and does not hold a public key. It is signed by the platform manufacturer, and should be validated against the manufacturer's certificate chain. The platform certificate holds the EK certificate's serial number in the signed portion, so that you have assurance that the platform manufacturer meant the two certificates to be paired.

Comment: I think the big benefit would be to have the private key of a certificate in the TPM. The idea is to write that once and not having the option to read it from TPM, just use it by encryption inside the TPM. So if there is no chance to extract the key, it would add security when we have to rollout a key. If a key is only stored in a 'normal' keystore of windows, there are tools like mimikatz that can extract the key!

Comment: Cert storage in TPM is very different than private key storage, and private key storage is not the only way to ensure that the TPM is the only entity capable of observing and using a private key. TPM 1.2 couldn't persistently store any private keys other than the EK and SRK. It could generate RSA 2048 keys, then return an encrypted blob to be stored off-chip. The TPM 2.0 works similarly, but does add the option of keeping the private key persistently on the chip. In neither case is it necessary to store the associated cert on the TPM.

Comment: If I understood that correct, a certificate in general does not include the private key. Sure there is a private key that is tied to the public key of the cert.

Comment: and this private key should be stored in TPM. The certificate (with only public key) is desigend to be public, so there is no need to bestored in TPM.

Comment: The TPM limits the "exposure" of the private key, but the mechanisms that do this aren't limited to storage. The private key is often stored outside the TPM, but encrypted in such a way that only the TPM can decrypt it. The best advantage the TPM provides is in performing private key operations (i.e. decryption and singing). Windows 10 has mechanisms to use the TPM in this way, though it's not straightforward to provide evidence that any particular key is protected by a TPM.  Without this evidence, you must rely on blind trust, which isn't usually a property of PKI anyone wants desires.

Comment: Hi @Lampshade, I'm new to TPM. My company manufactures hardware so I believe we are the "platform". You said those certificates have "designated index to store in TPM NV storage", but where can I find these designated indices? I know tpm2-tools has `tpm2_getekcertificate` to get the EK cert but I don't see a `tpm2_xxx` command for storing the platform certificate. I tried to store it in a regular NV index but the certificate is too long (~4000 bytes) but a NV index can hold only 2048 bytes at most.